# Probability of a prime factor

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

We are given an arbitrary number $n$ and a sequence of primes $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, ..., $p_k$. I am interested in the following question: Are the events "Prime $p_i$ is a factor of $n$" independent for distinct primes $p_i$?

It seems that the answer is no but I think this depends on the size of $n$. If $n$ is slightly greater than $p_k$ or lower than $p_k$, the answer is no. But what about the case where $n \geq \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$?

This is an intuition but I am not able to give a argument.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: count how many $x$ are divisible by $p_j$, $p_k\ne p_j$, and by both, in interval $[0,m\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^k p_i)$, for large $m$. Compare to the definition of: _the events "Prime $p_i$ is a factor of $n$" independent for distinct primes $p_i$_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Comment: @fkraiem Sorry, you are right, I got the wrong stackexchange :-/

Comment: Thank you @fgrieu . Yes I can check this experimentally, but why do you suggest to check this in this interval? Why not in $\left[\prod_ {i=1}^k p_i, (\prod_{i=1}^k p_i)^2\right]$?